# Find lines in an element and then wrap it with <span> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to write a code where I split the html by br, find lines that start with a number and then add in span tags.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var brExp = /<br\s*\/?>/i;
    var swn = /^[0-9]+[^)]/;
    var lines = $('.caption').html().split(brExp).filter(line => swn.test(line.trim()));;
    jQuery.each(lines, function() {
        console.log(this);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caption">
    BBQ Porked Rolls.

    Ingredients:
    3 to 4 pounds pork shoulder<br />
    1 tablespoon salt<br />
    2 tablespoons brown sugar<br />

    STEPS:
    In the oven,... 
<div>
```

I’ve already gotten the lines and all that’s left is to add in span tags around those lines without the need to create a new div for the result. Maybe by using `replace()`, `wrap()` or something else entirely. This is where I need help.

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
<span itemprop="recipeIngredient">3 to 4 pounds pork shoulder</span><br>
<span itemprop="recipeIngredient">1 tablespoon salt</span><br>
<span itemprop="recipeIngredient">2 tablespoons brown sugar</span><br>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to [map()](http://api.jquery.com/map/) over the collection.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var brExp = /<br\s*\/?>/i;
  var swn = /^\d/;
  var lines = $('.caption').html().split(brExp).map(function (line) {
        // strip the whitespace
        line = line.trim();
        // check for number
        if ( swn.test(line) ) {
          // add enclosing span
          line = '<span itemprop="recipeIngredient">' + line + '</span>';
        }
        // return the line for the new collection
        return line;
      }).join('<br />');
  $('.caption').html(lines);
});
```

If you only want to change the first line, you can make the following minor change to the code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var firstOnly = true; // will check for number when this value is true
  var brExp = /<br\s*\/?>/i;
  var swn = /^\d/;
  var lines = $('.caption').html().split(brExp).map(function (line) {
        // strip the whitespace
        line = line.trim();
        // check 'firstOnly' is true before checking for number
        if ( firstOnly && swn.test(line) ) {
          // add enclosing span
          line = '<span itemprop="recipeIngredient">' + line + '</span>';
          // first matching line has been modified
          // so set 'firstOnly' to false
          firstOnly = false;
        }
        // return the line for the new collection
        return line;
      }).join('<br />');
  $('.caption').html(lines);
});
```

Comment: You my friend are a genius. Thank you.

Comment: Hi Dan, what if I only want to wrap the first line? (this comment question is for another purpose). Before, I could just use `split(brExp)[0]` but in this case that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: I've added a code snippet for adding the <span> to the first matching line.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE**

You can try this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($)
{
    var html = '';

    var brExp = /<br\s*\/?>/i;
    var lines = $('.caption').html().split(brExp);
    jQuery.each(lines, function(index, value) {
        html += '<span>' + value + '</span></br>';
    });

    $('.caption').html(html);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach could be using .replace() as you said.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($)
    {

       var text = $(".caption").html();

       var newText = text.replace( /(\d+.+)(<br)/g, '<span itemprop="recipeIngredient">$1</span>$2');

       console.log(newText);

       $(".caption").html(text);

    });
```

the regex must be fixed a little, but i think the approach is valid.

https://jsfiddle.net/g6yegh1f/

Comment: I like this one!

Comment: I edited the question, the ingredients are not the only thing in the div so I dont want to totally remove all text in the div. Is there another way?

Comment: .replace() in this case just add some tags based on regex, other text not reached by regex keeps going. The advantage of this approach is that you would focus only in regex.

Answer (score 0):

Use this link which has the number check and then appending the data to span tag`https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZoaXYR?editors=1010`

```
var data = `3 to 4 pounds pork shoulder<br />1 tablespoon salt<br />2 tablespoons brown sugar<br />`;
var brExp = /<br\s*\/?>/i;
var swn = /^\d/;
var lines = data.split(brExp).filter(line => swn.test(line.trim()));
        $.each(lines, function() {
            var ff = Number(this[0]);
            alert(typeof(ff));
            if(typeof(ff) == "number") {
                alert("success");
                $("#first").append("<span id='test'>" +this+"</span>");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably do this:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  var brExp = /<br\s*\/?>/i;
  var swn = /^\d/;
  var lines = $('.caption').html().split(brExp)
  //create span
  lines=  lines.map( line =>$('<span />').prop('itemprop','recipeIngredient').html(line))//.join('<br />'); 
  //empty the div
  $('.caption').empty();
  jQuery.each(lines, function() {
        $('.caption').append(this);
  $('.caption').append('<br />');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="caption">
3 to 4 pounds pork shoulder<br />
1 tablespoon salt<br />
2 tablespoons brown sugar<br />
<div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the index to find the value that corresponds to the 0 key, check if it is a number and then use append/before methods to bind the same.

Comment: var data = `3 to 4 pounds pork shoulder<br />
1 tablespoon salt<br />
2 tablespoons brown sugar<br />`;
  var brExp = /<br\s*\/?>/i;
        var swn = /^\d/;
        var lines = data.split(brExp).filter(line => swn.test(line.trim()));
        $.each(lines, function() {
           alert(this);
          $("#first").append("<span id='test'>" +this+"</span>");
        });

Comment: @ManikandaPrabakaran I've removed the clarification request from your answer, please consider leaving those out in the future, as it's best suited in a comment. As for your links, please edit your answer and integrate them into it, explaining how they solve the problem. If possible, everything needed to solve the problem **should should be contained in the answer**.